# Apollo Client cache does not update

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using Apollo Server / Client and the cache does not seem to work on update mutations. (Create, Delete). The server gets updated but nothing happens on the front end. I have to reload the page to show the new item / show change of an item.

I followed the [Apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#updating-the-cache-after-a-mutation) and modeled it after their [sandbox implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutations-example-app-final-tjoje?file=/src/index.js:1595-2095).
Let me know if you need more of my code, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          createUser(
            {
              variables: {
                name: input.value,
                email: input.value,
                password: input.value
              }
            },
            {
              update(cache, { data: { createUser } }) {
                cache.modify({
                  fields: {
                    allUsers(existingUsers = []) {
                      const newUser = cache.writeFragment({
                        data: { createUser },
                        fragment: gql`
                          fragment NewUser on User {
                            name
                            email
                          }
                        `
                      });
                      return existingUsers.concat(newUser);
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          );
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide an `id` property in the `writeFragment` method. Here's the example on the docs:

```
client.writeFragment({
  id: '5',
  fragment: gql`
    fragment MyTodo on Todo {
      completed
    }
  `,
  data: {
    completed: true,
  },
});
```

Also, `writeFragment` returns `void`, so you need to use `readFragment` to get the data you want, or just use the data available in the mutation's result

Comment: I see that now in the docs - for updating objects in the cache. I am a little further down, trying to add a new object.

Comment: I figured it out - I had to attach it to the actual hook instead of attaching to the call of the hook.